# Ubuntu boot menu wont show up. It directely boots into Windows 8

Tags: boot

I recently wanted to dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 in my HP Envy M6 laptop. The entire install process went smoothly. When I reboot it automatically boots into Windows 8. BTW, Windows 8 was already pre-installed in my laptop. The only way for me to boot into Ubuntu is to press F9 and go into boot devices options and from there select Ubuntu.

I've tried using Boot Repair but it gives me an error (http://paste.ubuntu.com/7394197).

How do I make GRUB my default boot loader and from there boot into Windows? I desperately need help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you installed Ubuntu, did you answer yes to installing grub, or did you say no?

Sounds like you are using NTloader, which won't see Linux....

Try: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this guide to reinstall grub from Live CD (or Live USB):
http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Replace /dev/sdXY with /dev/sda6 (you linux partition) and /dev/sdX with /dev/sda